Conjecture about cyclic hexagons and tangent circles
Is the following conjecture true:

In every cyclic convex hexagon, there exists a point $P$ such that for every pair of opposite sides $s$ and $t$, the circle through $P$ and the endpoints of $s$, is tangent to the circle through $P$ and the endpoints of $t$.

In the diagram, circles associated with opposite sides are the same color. For brevity, I shall call such circles "opposite circles".

The conjecture seems to be true, based on experiments using Geometer's Sketchpad.
The conjecture is not generally true if:

the hexagaon is non-cyclic
the hexagon is inscribed in a non-circular ellipse
if we change "hexagon" to "$2n$-gon" with $n>3$

My attempt
I considered:

Lines through the centres of opposite circles
Lines through $P$ tangent to opposite circles
Lines that are tangent to opposite circles like an ice cream cone with two scoops of ice cream
Labelling the vertices anticlockwise $ABCDEF$, then drawing $AE$ extended, and $BD$ extended

But I could not find anything useful.
Any proof must use the fact that the polygon has six sides, and is cyclic; but how?
Context
Recently I discovered that, in any tangential quadrilateral $ABCD$ with incentre $O$, the circle through $A,B,O$ is tangent to the circle through $C,D,O$. (This is easily proved by extending opposite sides to form a triangle, and using the incentre-excentre lemma.) I tried to generalize this fact. I didn't generalize it, but instead came up with the conjecture here.
EDIT:
More experimenting suggests that $P$ always lies somewhere on the the line segment connecting the centre of the circle and the incentre of $\triangle ABC$, where $A,B,C$ are the intersections of the hexagon's diagonals that connect opposite points.

Is the cyclic hexagon convex?

@DuongNgo Yes, the cyclic hexagon is convex.

Would a proof based on conformal mapping work? We'd start with a regular hexagon, find a bilinear conformal map that maps the vertices to six general concyclic points, and the image of the center is then the general $P$.

@Dan $P$ doesn't lie on the line connecting the circumcenter and the incenter of triangle $ABC$.

@OscarLanzi I have no idea how to construct such a conformal map. Could you give an explicit construction or prove that one exists?

@Dan yes, I meant the circumcenter of the cyclic hexagon.

@Dan I updated my answer.

Update: I rewrote my answer completely since I've got proof now.
Denote the cyclic convex hexagon by $ABCDEF$ and its circumcenter by $O$.
The idea
Let $X$ be the intersection of $AB$ and $DE$, $Y$ the intersection of $BC$ and $EF$, $Z$ the intersection of $CD$ and $FA$. $X, Y, Z$ are collinear according to Pascal's theorem. The following cases are exhaustive.
Case 1. $X, Y, Z$ are points at infinity.
In this case, $\odot(OAB)$ is tangent to $\odot(ODE)$, $\odot(OBC)$ is tangent to $\odot(OEF)$, and $\odot(OCD)$ is tangent to $\odot(OFA)$, where $O$ is the circumcenter of $ABCDEF$.
Case 2. $X, Y, Z$ are not points at infinity.

Since $ABCDEF$ is convex, $X, Y, Z$ are exterior points of the circumcircle of $ABCDEF$, so there are circles centered at $X, Y, Z$ which are orthogonal to the circumcircle of $ABCDEF$.
Case 3. There is exactly one point among $X, Y, Z$ which lies at infinity.
Without loss of generality, assume that $Y, Z$ are not points at infinity, then $AB \parallel DE \parallel YZ$ and there are circles centered at $Y, Z$, which are orthogonal to the circumcircle of $ABCDEF$. The radical axis of $\odot(Y), \odot(Z)$ is the common perpendicular bisector of $AB$ and $DE$.
In cases 2 and 3, if one can show that $\odot(Y)$ and $\odot(Z)$ have a common point, then that point satisfies. Proving the existence of the intersection of $\odot(Y)$ and $\odot(Z)$ can be reduced to showing that the distance from the circumcenter of $ABCDEF$ to the Pascal line $YZ$ is greater than the circumradius of $ABCDEF$.
Some properties of pole and polar with respect to a circle
I list some properties that will be used later in the proof of the conjecture.
Pole and polar are defined with conics as well but in this problem, we only use a circle, hence only need a definition of polar and polar with respect to a circle.

Given a circle $\odot(O)$ with radius $R$.
For any point $P\ne O$, there is a point $Q$ on the ray $OP$ such that $\overline{OP}\cdot\overline{OQ} = R^{2}$. The line through $Q$ and perpendicular to $OP$ is called the polar of $P$ with respect to $\odot(O)$.
For any line $\ell$ not passing through $O$, there is a point $K$ such that $OK$ is perpendicular $\ell$ and $\overline{OK}\cdot\overline{OH} = R^{2}$, where $H$ is the orthogonal projection of $O$ onto $\ell$. The point $K$ is called the pole of $\ell$ with respect to $\odot(O)$.

From this definition, we deduce that a line is in the exterior of a circle if and only if its pole is in the interior of that circle.

Theorem 1 (La Hire). Given a circle $\odot(O)$.
(polar style) The point $P$ lies on the polar of the point $Q$ with respect to $\odot(O)$ if and only if $Q$ lies on the polar of $P$ with respect to $\odot(O)$.
(pole style) The $\ell$ passes through the pole of the line $k$ with respect to $\odot(O)$ if and only if $k$ passes through the pole of $\ell$ with respect to $\odot(O)$.


Theorem 2 (construction of polar using tangents and secants) Given a circle $\odot(O)$ and a point $M$ which is in the exterior of $\odot(O)$. $MP, MQ$ are the tangent lines of $\odot(O)$ such that $P, Q$ lie on $\odot(O)$ ($PQ$ is the polar of $M$ with respect to $\odot(O)$). Two distinct secants of $\odot(O)$ through $M$ intersect $\odot(O)$ at $A, B$ and $C, D$, respectively. If $AC$ intersects $BD$ then the intersection lies on $PQ$.

The proof
It suffices to work on case 2 and case 3, which can be "merged" (by forgetting one intersection). Without loss of generality, let's rewrite the statement for these two cases.

$ABCDEF$ is a cyclic convex hexagon with circumcenter $O$. Suppose that $BC$ intersects $EF$ at $Y$, $CD$ intersects $FA$ at $Z$.
(i) The line $YZ$ is in the exterior of $\odot(O)$.
(ii) There exists a point $P$ such that $\odot(PBC), \odot(PCD)$ are tangent to $\odot(PEF), \odot(PFA)$, respectively.
(iii) $\odot(PAB)$ is tangent to $\odot(PDE)$, where $P$ is the point in part (ii).

Proof of (i) is tricky. Readers should pay attention to the figure.
(i) To show that $YZ$ is in the exterior of $\odot(O)$, we will prove that the pole of $YZ$ with respect to $\odot(O)$ is in the interior of $\odot(O)$.
$ABCDEF$ is convex so $BCEF$ and $CDFA$ are convex. Hence $Y$ lies on the extension of $BC$ and that of $EF$, $Z$ lies on the extension of $CD$ and that of $FA$, so $Y, Z$ are in the exterior of $\odot(O)$.
Let $A'$ be the intersection of $BE$ and $CF$, $B'$ be the intersection of $CF$ and $AD$, $C'$ be the intersection of $AD$ and $BE$. $A', B', C'$ are interior points of $\odot(O)$.
Let $YY_{1}, YY_{2}$ be the tangent lines of $\odot(O)$ ($Y_{1}, Y_{2}$ lie on $\odot(O)$) and $ZZ_{1}, ZZ_{2}$ be the tangent lines of $\odot(O)$ ($Z_{1}, Z_{2}$ lie on $\odot(O)$). By Theorem 2, $Y_{1}, Y_{2}, A'$ are collinear and $Z_{1}, Z_{2}, B'$ are collinear.

Either $A', B', C'$ are identical or they form a triangle. If $A', B', C'$ are identical then $A'$ is the pole of $YZ$ according to La Hire's theorem.
Otherwise, $A', B', C'$ form a triangle. We will show that the intersection of $Y_{1}Y_{2}$ and $Z_{1}Z_{2}$ is in the interior of triangle $A'B'C'$.

Let $G$ be the intersection of $Y_{1}Y_{2}$ and $EF$; $T$ be the intersection other than $A$ of $AA'$ and $\odot(O)$.
$Y_{1}EY_{2}F$ is a harmonic quadrigon so $G$ lies in the line segment $EF$. $AT$ splits the plane into two half-planes. Denote the half-plane containing $B, C$ by $\mathcal{H}_{1}$ and the other by $\mathcal{H}_{2}$. Without loss of generality, suppose that $D$ is in $\mathcal{H}_{2}$, then the line segment $AD$ lies entirely in $\mathcal{H}_{2}$. Therefore $B'$ lies in the line segment $A'F$ and $C'$ lies in the line segment $A'E$. Hence $Y_{1}Y_{2}$ intersects the line segment $B'C'$.
Analogously, we can prove that $Z_{1}Z_{2}$ intersects the line segment $C'A'$. Therefore the intersection of $Y_{1}Y_{2}$ and $Z_{1}Z_{2}$ is in the interior of triangle $A'B'C'$, which means the pole of $YZ$ is in the interior of triangle $A'B'C'$, hence in the interior of $\odot(O)$. Therefore $YZ$ is in the exterior of $\odot(O)$.
(ii) Let $H$ be the orthogonal projection of $O$ onto $YZ$. Construct $P, P'$ on $OH$ such that
$$
\overline{HP}^{2} = \overline{HP'}^{2} = {OH}^{2} - R^{2}
$$

where $R$ is the circumradius of $\odot(O)$. The points $P, P'$ exist because $OH > R$. By Pythagoras' theorem
\begin{align*}
  {YP'}^{2} = {YP}^{2} = {YH}^{2} + {HP}^{2} = {OY}^{2} - {OH}^{2} + {OH}^{2} - R^{2} = {OY}^{2} - R^{2} = {YY_{1}}^{2} = {YY_{2}}^{2} \\
  {ZP'}^{2} = {ZP}^{2} = {ZH}^{2} + {HP}^{2} = {OZ}^{2} - {OH}^{2} + {OH}^{2} - R^{2} = {OZ}^{2} - R^{2} = {ZZ_{1}}^{2} = {ZZ_{2}}^{2}
\end{align*}
it follows that $\odot(Y, YY_{1})$ and $\odot(Z, ZZ_{1})$ (they are orthogonal to $\odot(O)$) pass through $P$ and $P'$. By the tangent-secant theorem
\begin{align*}
  {YP'}^{2} = {YP}^{2} = {YY_{1}}^{2} = {YY_{2}}^{2} = \overline{YB}\cdot\overline{YC} = \overline{YE}\cdot\overline{YF} \\
  {ZP'}^{2} = {ZP}^{2} = {ZZ_{1}}^{2} = {ZZ_{2}}^{2} = \overline{ZC}\cdot\overline{ZD} = \overline{ZF}\cdot\overline{ZA}
\end{align*}
Therefore $\odot(PBC)$ is tangent to $\odot(PEF)$ (as they are tangent to $PY$), $\odot(PCD)$ is tangent to $\odot(PFA)$ (as they are tangent to $PZ$).
(iii) If $AB$ intersects $DE$ (denote the intersection by $X$) then we apply (ii) to $BCDEFA$ to obtain that $\odot(PAB)$ is tangent to $\odot(PDE)$ at $P$.
If $AB$ is parallel to $DE$ then $AB \parallel DE \parallel YZ$. In this case, $OP$ (which is perpendicular to $YZ$) is the common perpendicular bisector of $AB$ and $DE$, hence $\odot(PAB)$ is tangent to $\odot(PDE)$ at $P$ as the circumcenters of these two triangles lie on $OP$.
Q.E.D.

Wow, this looks great. I will need some time to try to understand this. Thank you.
